# Finding one parameter using another in a document MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

For example, I have a document:

```
{
    "_id": "59f70449ee870802b43de37c",
    "email": "johnsmith@gmail.com",
    "password": "test123",
    "__v": 0
}
```

How do I access 'password' by only knowing 'email'? I'm trying to write it so that once I find email, I will then use it to check its password.

Comment: I think you mean `.findOne({ "email": email, "password": password })` which is an AND query for BOTH conditions. Otherwise you just query by "email" and then use the `password` of the returned document with a decrypt or similar. Typically you don't. And simply would hash the password at best in storage, and do the same on query input as shown.

Comment: My problem is, password is already hashed in side the DB. So the password typed in my front end is not the same when comparing it to what's in the DB, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Yes I understand what you are asking, but like I told you "typically you do not not that". Instead use the same "hashing/crypto" on the plain text input for password as it is stored in the database **before** you issue the query. If nothing returns, the password is not matched. That's how the rest of the world has been doing it for many years. It's like asking *"how to I undo a bolt with a screwdriver?"*. So typically, you do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Neil suggested you can use find query to get the password .

You said your password is decrypted . So first thing check out from where the crypt algorithm was applied in password . Identify the hashing algorithm applied in password .

why you need to fetch password .I think to compare to some send password from frontend for login purpose, it is always critical not to fetch it in frontend .

This is the strategy you can follow .

1) Check which crypto is applied to password in mongodb , the password may be changed at time of saving by backend application.

2) Then when you want to compare password you can convert sent password by same algorithm and compare the both password.

most of the time we use an algorithm which can not be converted to original password , so this is the strategy .